# 行ごとに計算した結果を１列に代入する

Tags: r

もし、ご助言いただけると大変助かります。

以下のようなことをしたいと思っております。

・df(下記)の２～４列目の値をそれぞれ5列目の値で割る。

・その結果を行ごとに新たに作成したdf_chaの3列目に代入したい。

・つまりdf_chaの3列目には上から0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3という値が入るようにしたい。

アドバイスいただけると助かります。

```
# データフレームの作成
treatment   <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
alive   <- c(60, 50, 30, 20)
fire  <- c(0, 20, 50, 50)
dry <- c(40, 30, 20, 30)
total <-  c(100, 100, 100, 100)
df <- data.frame(treatment, alive, fire, dry, total)
# 空のマトリックス作成。3列目に計算結果を入れたい。
df_cha <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 12, ncol = 3)
df_cha [, 1] <- rep(c("A","B"), each = 6)
df_cha_clnm <- colnames(df)[2:4]
df_cha [,2] <- rep(df_cha_clnm, 4)コードをここに入力
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gather`で縦持ちに変換後、`mutate`で計算し、`arrange`で並び替えを行うことで可能です。

```
df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  gather(col, value, -treatment, -total, -rowid) %>% 
  mutate(value = value/total) %>% 
  arrange(rowid) %>% select(-rowid, -total)
```

Comment: どうもありがとうございました！できました！！助かりました